# Compare two strings and find mismatch and match and count them both in perl

Tags: string, perl

Compare two strings and find mismatch and mismatch and count them both

```
string1 = "SEQUENCE"
string2 = "SEKUEAEE"
```

I want output like. With the mismatch and match count.

```
'SS' match 1
'EE' match 3
'UU' match 1
'QK' mismatch 1
'NA' mismatch 1
'CE' mismatch 1
```

Comment: I can write a script to do this, but how are you getting these strings, from an array, hash, or from a text file?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution in old Perl. Also works with however many strings you want

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::AllUtils qw( mesh part count_by pairs );

my @strings = ("SEQUENCES", "SEKUEAEES", "SEKUEAEES"); 

my $i = 0;

print join "",
    map { $_->[0] . " " . ($_->[1] > 1 ? 'match' : 'mismatch') . " " . $_->[1] ."\n" }
    pairs
    count_by { $_ }
    map { join "", @$_ }
    part { int($i++/scalar @strings) } 
    &mesh( @{[ map { [ split // ] } @strings ]} ) 
;
```

And here for comparison, analogous code in Perl 6.

```
my @strings = "SEQUENCES", "SEKUEAEES", "SEKUEAEES"; 

([Z] @strings>>.comb)
    .map({ .join })
    .Bag
    .map({ "{.key} { .value > 1 ?? 'match' !! 'mismatch' } {.value}\n" })
    .join
    .say;
```

Isn't that just pretty?

Answer (score 2):

Solution that works for any amount of strings.

```
use List::Util qw(max);
use Perl6::Junction qw(all);

my @strings = qw(SEQUENCE SEKUEAEE);
my (%matches, %mismatches);
for my $i (0 .. -1 + max map { length } @strings) {
    my @c = map { substr $_, $i, 1 } @strings;
    if ($c[0] eq all @c) {
        $matches{join '', @c}++;
    } else {
        $mismatches{join '', @c}++;
    }
}
for my $k (keys %matches) {
    printf "'%s' match %d\n", $k, $matches{$k};
}
for my $k (keys %mismatches) {
    printf "'%s' mismatch %d\n", $k, $mismatches{$k};
}
__END__
'SS' match 1
'UU' match 1
'EE' match 3
'QK' mismatch 1
'NA' mismatch 1
'CE' mismatch 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Useing the non-core but very handy [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/each_array/;

sub count_matches {
  die "strings must be equal length!" unless length $_[0] == length $_[1];
  my @letters1 = split //, $_[0];
  my @letters2 = split //, $_[1];
  my (%matches, %mismatches);
  my $iter = each_array @letters1, @letters2;
  while (my ($c1, $c2) = $iter->()) {
    if ($c1 eq $c2) {
      $matches{"$c1$c2"} += 1;
    } else {
      $mismatches{"$c1$c2"} += 1;
    }
  }
  say "'$_' match $matches{$_}" for sort keys %matches;
  say "'$_' mismatch $mismatches{$_}" for sort keys %mismatches;
}

count_matches qw/SEQUENCE SEKUEAEE/;
```

Comment: You may have more Utils, but I have ALL Utils. Hahaha. (see below)

Comment: @Holli That makes me want to make use of `List::EvenMoreUtils`.